# How to use host's pcap in docker container?

Tags: docker, containers, tcpdump, libpcap

I want to capture a specific network of hosts from docker container.

host <-> host // 
How do I capture a specific port of tcp that communicates with the host?

I want to know how to set it in the container.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the container with `network_mode=host`:

```
docker run --net=host ...
```

See https://hub.docker.com/r/kaazing/tcpdump for more examples